# Differentiability of a function defined on the sphere

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

sorry for stupid question.

The statement "let $f: \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{R}$  be differentiable on the sphere" seems straightforward enough. But what does it *really* mean to be differentiable, continuous etc on the sphere? I struggle to find a proper definition. Should I try to use charts/atlases or something in order to define it rigourously?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole point of charts.

Comment: Could you point me to a reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold